# How to deal with Font appearing differently across browsers

Tags: fonts, cross-browser

We are using the Titlium font across our main menu navigation items, which is from file "TitilliumWeb-Regular.ttf".

How come the font looks different in Firefox than it does in Chrome? I seem to find one appears quite jagged when I compare them. Is this just standard Browser behaviour or is there something I can do to improve this?

The site in question is here - http://www.microserveltd.co.uk

Comment: mesmerizing site by the way

Answer (score 1):

they differ because windows browsers implement their own rasterization engines to convert vector fonts to pixels -> different implementations = different results. one easy fix for WebKit is to add `-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased` to your font declarations, but that should be used warily and clearly won't help for non-WebKit browsers. 
also, you're only serving up .ttf font formats, if you served up multiple types of files you'll get better cross-browser/cross-platform performance. you can generate the @font-face styles at [font squirrel](http://fontsquirrel.com) and you can read about the value of OTF vs TTF here: http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/2010/12/the-benefits-of-opentypecff-over-truetype.html